# Intutive understanding of internal energy

Tags: thermodynamics

Our high school teacher told us that once we calculate the formula of internal energy, it is valid everywhere. I cannot understand how? I asked him, he simply answered because it is state function. It made me even more confused.

---

From first law, $\mathrm dU=\mathrm dq+\mathrm dW$

In constant volume process, volume differntial $\mathrm dV=0$, hence $\mathrm dW=0$, so

$(\mathrm dU)_V=(\mathrm dq)_V$ and $(\mathrm dq)_V=C_V\mathrm dT$

> So, $(\mathrm dU)_V=C_V\mathrm dT$

---

Why we use this formula everywhere even when volume is changing (since we derived this relation for a constant volume process), at least for ideal gas?

Comment: This formula is used only when the process occurs at constant volume like a reaction occurs in closed vessel in which gaseous reactants converts to gaseous products. As volume is fixed so there is no expansion or contraction work.

Comment: Energy is a state function, but that only matters if you're going from the same point A to the same point B **every time**. In the formula where you have derived, the process is constant-volume, so the system at points A and B must have the same volume. Now if you have a process in which the volume changes, like point A to point C where the system at C has some different volume, then the energy change for A->C won't be the same as A->B, because the initial and final states aren't the same, and your formula becomes invalid. Unfortunately your teacher is not explaining this very well.

Comment: Because, for an ideal gas, internal energy is a function only of temperature.  So it doesn't matter what the volume change is.  For a non-ideal gas, it can also be a function of volume.

Comment: @ChetMiller Is this because of ideal gas' molecules do not have attractive forces?

Answer (score 2):

For an arbitrary fluid (not necessarily an ideal gas), a combination of the first- and second laws of thermodynamics tells us that, $$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\right)_T=-\left[P-T\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_v\right]$$where U is the molar internal energy and v is the molar volume.  For a fluid which obeys the ideal gas law Pv=RT, the right hand side of this equation is zero.  So the internal energy of a substance which obeys the ideal gas law is independent of volume.  An ideal gas is a substance which obeys the ideal gas law because the interactive forces between its molecules are negligible.  So, yes, it is because ideal gas molecules do not have attractive forces.

Comment: I think you misswrote the partial derivative on the rhs.

Comment: @BuckThorn Thanx.  Ive corrected it.

Comment: I might say, even for a HS student, something like: "ideal gas molecules do not have any attractive or repulsive forces". But that's a judgement call.